# how to pass parameter to a javascript function using struts taglib?

Tags: java, javascript, struts, taglib

1. I have a javascript function `updateHiddenField(value)` that gets a value as parameter and then sets this value as the value of a hidden field.
2. I have a JavaBean `flight` with parameters `id` and `flightNo`.

**Problem:** How can I pass the parameter `id` of JavaBean `flight` to the js function `updateHiddenField(value)` when using `<html:link>` tag(struts)?

```
<html:link href="javascript:updateHiddenField(idToPassHere)"><bean:write name="flight" property="flightNo"/></html:link>
```

Thanks
Umar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html:link href="javascript:updateHiddenField(<s:property value="id"/>)"><bean:write name="flight" property="flightNo"/></html:link>
```

Assuming your taglib import is `<% @taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>`

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be gaining anything by using `<html:link>` over `<a>` - so that would be the easiest change:

`<a href="javascript:updateHiddenField(<bean:write name="flight" property="id"/>)">`
    `<bean:write name="flight" property="flightNo"/>`
`</a>`

More generally I would suggest you add event listeners to your DOM objects, rather than mixing markup & functionality.